# How to load .mat file which has a variable filename?

Tags: matlab, matlab-load

```
%select all .mat files

oar = dir('*oar.mat'); n = {oar.name};

%loop through files

for l=1:length(oar);

load pat_oar(l) %<---this is the .mat file with variable filename


clear ...

end
```

How do I write some Matlab script that will read in one .mat file after another...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You file names are stored in `n`, so you should be able to do:

```
for l=1:length(oar)
    load(n{l})
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the functional form.  Instead of:

```
load pat_oar{I}
```

Use

```
load(pat_oar{I})
```

Calling a Matlab command using the unix-style syntax (i.e. `command arg1 arg2`) is just syntax shorthand for the more verbose syntax of `command('arg1','arg2')`.  It's a pretty common trick to use the more verbose syntax anytime an argument is stored in a variable.